# Use Smart Card for login using 'Microsoft Remote Desktop' from macOS

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I am using MacBook Pro 2020 macOS 12.6.8

I have to connect to Window 10 Desktop.

I have 'Microsoft Remote Desktop' Version 10.9.2 (2147)

My compony enforces users to use only PIV card login.

I create a new connection and a field 'User account' I select 'Ask when required'.

Unfortunately when I try to connect it provides me the option only for username and password.

Why it does not give me the option for PIV (card reader).

Note: my PIV and Card reader are OK and I could use it with other application e.g. Citrix.

It sounds to me like 'Microsoft Remote Desktop' issue ..

Could someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Configure Smart Card Login
Launch the Microsoft Remote Desktop application.
Click on the "Microsoft Remote Desktop" menu in the top left corner of the screen and select "Preferences."
In the Preferences window, navigate to the "User Account" tab.
Click on the "Configure" button next to the "User Account" field.
In the User Account Configuration window, select the "Smart card" option.
Click on the "Configure" button next to the "Smart card" field.
Insert your smart card into the card reader connected to your macOS device.
Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the smart card configuration process.
Once the smart card is successfully configured, click "Save" to apply the changes.
Step 3: Connect to a Remote Windows Computer
Launch the Microsoft Remote Desktop application.
Click on the "+" button in the top left corner of the screen to add a new remote desktop connection.
In the Add Desktop window, enter the necessary details to connect to the remote Windows computer, such as the PC name, user account, and gateway (if applicable).
Click "Add" to save the connection.
Double-click on the newly added connection to initiate the remote desktop session.
When prompted, insert your smart card into the card reader.
Enter the PIN code associated with your smart card.
If the authentication is successful, you will be logged in to the remote Windows computer.

https://usercomp.com/news/1066491/smart-card-login-with-microsoft-remote-desktop-on-macos

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).